# How to block a spot when playing tic tac toe, if i clicked on it, or when the game is over

Tags: java

I have a problem, I have a game, tic tac toe, and i can't figure out how to make it so when someone wins or someone moves it blocks the certain spot, and when someone wins it will not let you do anything, it is inside a JFrame, I can always keep changing the O and X
Here is the code

```
package project;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Project extends JFrame
{
    static JButton startButton = new JButton();

    static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("src/project/imagesX1.jpg");
    static ImageIcon imageX = new ImageIcon("src/project/images1.jpg");

    static JButton restart = new JButton();

    static JLabel label0 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label8 = new JLabel();

    static JLabel vert1 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel vert2 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel horiz1 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel horiz2 = new JLabel();

    static JLabel showWinner = new JLabel();

    static int[] gridMark = new int[9];
    static boolean xTurn = true;
    static int numberClicks = 0;
    static Timer drawTimer;

    static JLabel[] choiceLabel = new JLabel[9];
    static int[] labelValue = new int[9];

    static int screen = 0;

    static int whosTurn = 0;
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Project().show();
    }
    public Project()
    {
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
                {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())), (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());



        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            gridMark[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            labelValue[i] = 0;
        }

        choiceLabel[0] = label0;
        choiceLabel[1] = label1;
        choiceLabel[2] = label2;
        choiceLabel[3] = label3;
        choiceLabel[4] = label4;
        choiceLabel[5] = label5;
        choiceLabel[6] = label6;
        choiceLabel[7] = label7;
        choiceLabel[8] = label8;

        //ROW 1
        int x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
            choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            choiceLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()));
            choiceLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
            choiceLabel[i].setForeground(Color.black);
            myGrid.gridx = x;
            x+=2;
            myGrid.gridy = 0;
            //gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            myGrid.ipadx = 40;
            myGrid.ipady = 40;
            getContentPane().add(choiceLabel[i], myGrid);
            choiceLabel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    labelMouseClicked(e);
                }
            });
        }

        //ROW 2
        x = 0;

        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
            choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            choiceLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()));
            choiceLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
            choiceLabel[i].setForeground(Color.black);
            myGrid.gridx = x;
            x+=2;
            myGrid.gridy = 3;
            myGrid.ipadx = 40;
            myGrid.ipady = 40;
            getContentPane().add(choiceLabel[i], myGrid);
            choiceLabel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    labelMouseClicked(e);
                }
            });
        }

        //ROW 3
        x = 0;

        for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
        {
            myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
            choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            choiceLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()));
            choiceLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
            choiceLabel[i].setForeground(Color.black);
            myGrid.gridx = x;
            x+=2;
            myGrid.gridy = 5;
            myGrid.ipadx = 40;
            myGrid.ipady = 40;
            getContentPane().add(choiceLabel[i], myGrid);
            choiceLabel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    labelMouseClicked(e);
                }
            });
        }

        myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        horiz1.setOpaque(true);
        horiz1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        myGrid.gridx = 0;
        myGrid.gridy = 1;
        myGrid.gridwidth = 5;
        myGrid.ipadx = 500;
        myGrid.ipady = 2;
        getContentPane().add(horiz1, myGrid);

        myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        horiz2.setOpaque(true);
        horiz2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        myGrid.gridx = 0;
        myGrid.gridy = 4;
        myGrid.gridwidth = 5;
        myGrid.ipadx = 500;
        myGrid.ipady = 2;
        getContentPane().add(horiz2, myGrid);

        myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        vert1.setOpaque(true);
        vert1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        vert1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        myGrid.gridx = 1;
        myGrid.gridy = 0;
        myGrid.gridheight = 6;
        myGrid.ipadx = 2;
        myGrid.ipady = 500;
        //gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        getContentPane().add(vert1, myGrid);

        myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        vert2.setOpaque(true);
        vert2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        myGrid.gridx = 3;
        myGrid.gridy = 0;
        myGrid.gridheight = 6;
        myGrid.ipadx = 2;
        myGrid.ipady = 500;
        //gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        getContentPane().add(vert2, myGrid);


        myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        showWinner.setBackground(Color.white);
        showWinner.setOpaque(true);
        myGrid.gridx = 0;
        myGrid.gridy = 6;
        myGrid.gridwidth = 5;
        myGrid.gridheight = 6;
        getContentPane().add(showWinner, myGrid);

        restart.setText("Restart");
        myGrid.gridx = 1;
        myGrid.gridy = 7;
        getContentPane().add(restart, myGrid);
        restart.setVisible(false);
        restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                restartActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        pack();
    }

    private void labelMouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Component clickedComponent = e.getComponent();
        int choice;
        for (choice = 0; choice < 9; choice++)
        {
            if (clickedComponent == choiceLabel[choice])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        choiceLabel[choice].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        if (whosTurn == 0)
        {
            choiceLabel[choice].setIcon(image);
            labelValue[choice] = 1;
            whosTurn = 1;
        }


        else if (whosTurn == 1)
        {
            choiceLabel[choice].setIcon(imageX);
            labelValue[choice] = 5;
            whosTurn = 0;
        }

        counter += 1;
        checkWinner();
    }
    public static void checkWinner()
    {
        if (labelValue[0] + labelValue[1] + labelValue[2] == 3 || labelValue[3] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[5] == 3 || labelValue[6] + labelValue[7] + labelValue[8] == 3 ||
                labelValue[0] + labelValue[3] + labelValue[6] == 3 || labelValue[1] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[7] == 3 || labelValue[2] + labelValue[5] + labelValue[8] == 3 || 
                labelValue[0] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[8] == 3 || labelValue[2] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[6] == 3)
        {
            showWinner.setFont(new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD, 30));
            showWinner.setText("X wins!");
            restart.setVisible(true);

        }

        else if (labelValue[0] + labelValue[1] + labelValue[2] == 15 || labelValue[3] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[5] == 15 || labelValue[6] + labelValue[7] + labelValue[8] == 15 ||
                labelValue[0] + labelValue[3] + labelValue[6] == 15 || labelValue[1] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[7] == 15 || labelValue[2] + labelValue[5] + labelValue[8] == 15 || 
                labelValue[0] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[8] == 15 || labelValue[2] + labelValue[4] + labelValue[6] == 15)
        {
            showWinner.setFont(new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD, 30));
            showWinner.setText("O wins!");
            restart.setVisible(true);
        }

        else if (counter == 9)
        {
            showWinner.setFont(new Font("Arial" , Font.BOLD, 30));
            showWinner.setText("It's a draw");
            restart.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    public static int getGridSelected (int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        if(gridMark[a] + gridMark[b] + gridMark[c] == d)
        {
            if(gridMark[a] == 0) return a;
            else if(gridMark[b] == 0) return b;
            else if(gridMark[c] == 0) return c;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void restartActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }
}
```

AI FOR FRAME:

```
public static void makeMove()
{
    myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    int gridSelected;
    int y;
    Random r = new Random();
    Graphics myGraphics = myFrame.getGraphics();

    //find gridSelected for "can win"
    if (getGridSelected(0,1,2,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,1,2,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(3,4,5,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(3,4,5,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(6,7,8,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(6,7,8,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(0,3,6,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,3,6,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(1,4,7,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(1,4,7,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(2,5,8,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(2,5,8,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(0,4,8,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,4,8,10);
    else if (getGridSelected(2,4,6,10) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(2,4,6,10);

    //find gridSelected for "block win"
    else if (getGridSelected(0,1,2,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,1,2,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(3,4,5,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(3,4,5,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(6,7,8,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(6,7,8,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(0,3,6,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,3,6,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(1,4,7,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(1,4,7,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(2,5,8,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(2,5,8,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(0,4,8,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(0,4,8,2);
    else if (getGridSelected(2,4,6,2) != -1) gridSelected = getGridSelected(2,4,6,2);

    //is the center available?
    else if (gridMark[4] == 0)gridSelected = 4;

    //if all else fail pick a random blank square
    else
    {
        while(true)
        {
            gridSelected = r.nextInt(9);
            if (gridMark[gridSelected] == 0)break;
        }
    }
    int x = 40 + (gridSelected % 3) * 80;
    if (gridSelected <= 2) y = 50;
    else if (gridSelected <= 5) y = 130;
    else y = 210;

    // draw O
    gridMark[gridSelected] = 5;
    myGraphics.setColor(Color.red);
    myGraphics.drawOval(x, y, 60, 60);
    checkWinner();
    xTurn = true;
    if (numberClicks != 10)
    {
        numberClicks++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Project extends JFrame
{
    static boolean gameHasEnded;

    ...

    public Project()
    {
        ...
        gameHasEnded = false;
    }

    ...

    private void labelMouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // If any player has already won, abort. Label will not be changed.
        // Players turn will not be switched.
        if (gameHasEnded) return;

        ...

        // If the label has already been clicked, abort.
        if (labelValue[choice] != 0) return;

        choiceLabel[choice].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        ...
    }

    public static void checkWinner()
    {
        ...
        restart.setVisible(true);
        gameHasEnded = true;
        ...
        restart.setVisible(true);
        gameHasEnded = true;
        ...
        restart.setVisible(true);
        gameHasEnded = true;
        ...
    }

    public void restartActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            labelValue[i] = 0;
            choiceLabel[i].setIcon(null);
            choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        showWinner.setText("");
        restart.setVisible(false);
        counter = 0;
        whosTurn = 0;
        gameHasEnded = false;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** You seem to have two "grids". The JFrame version uses `labelValue` and the Fame version `gridMark`.

1. Remove the declarations of the fields `gridMark`, `numberClicks` and `xTurn`, since they should not be used.
2. Replace all references to `gridMark` with `labelValue`.
3. Replace all references to `numberClicks` with `counter`.
4. Change `xTurn = true;` to `whosTurn = 0;`.
5. Replace the drawing commands. (E.g. `myGraphics.drawOval(x, y, 60, 60);`) with `choiceLabel[gridSelected].setIcon(imageX);`
6. After the call to `checkWinner()` in `labelMouseClicked`, insert this:

   ```
   if (!gameHasEnded)
   {
       makeMove();
   }
   ```

One tip: Remove all fields you are not using in the JFrame-version. This will make all references to Frame-version variables to be highlighted as errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually helped, it was so confusing for me, even tho i have done this before but in a Frame, and it is different in a JFrame. I can't say how much i am thankful! I maybe have 1 last request, can i make it to play versus the computer just like in a frame? I will put in the code for the frame, but i am not sure about the JFrame. Thanks Again.

Comment: Could you maybe please tell me your email? i have a few question to ask about java and how to make something. thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me. If you can (since you have done so much for me) could tell me how can i make so the restart button appears below the showWinner Label? I even tried changing the Height, still stays at the same spot. I even changed the Y value to 10, still nothing. Thanks once again, this really helped!

Comment: i also have a question. Where can i learn more about java and C#/C++? Where did you learn all of the languages? I have been doing Java for about 1 year now, and i learned a lot of different stuff, i would like to expand my knowledge ;)

Comment: You are using a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to layout the controls. It functions similar to a HTML table, where you can place controls in cells, or span multiple cells. To change a control's position, change the cell coordinate: `myGrid.gridx` and `myGrid.gridy`.

Comment: yes i know that, but even if i put the restart button in at coordinates myGrid.gridx = 1, or myGrid.gridx = 10, or myGrid.gridy = 7, myGrid.gridy = 10, it will be in the same place for some reason, this is why its confusing

Comment: is there another way to do it? maybe layerdedpanes? even tho i don't know those.

Answer (score 0):

In `labelMouseClicked()` you have to check if the field is already clicked. For example check `choiceLabel[choice].getBackground()`:

```
if (choiceLabel[choice].getBackground().equal(Color.WHITE))
{
  // already clicked
  return;
}
```

To check if the game is over you may return a boolean value in `checkWinner()` or better make a new function for it: `isGameEnd()`. You could use it in `labelMouseClicked()` and `checkWinner()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for the block field, it actually doesn't let me do anything